# Why can't a blueprints project edit BPs derived from c++ classes?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I am working in a relatively small team.

Now, because our IT guy is incredibly unhelpful, we don't yet have VS on all the machines (as I know this would solve the error). However, I'm still curious as to the answer to this question.

Computer A:

- C++ project
- Creates C++ classes
- Creates BP derived from said C++ classes.
- Sends project to Computer B.

Computer B:

- Gets project
- Tries to edit BP classes
- Can't open them
- Reason: 'They derive from parent C++ classes'

---

So my base question is really why is this?

I understand that this can be solved easily, but I'm interested as to why Unreal imposes these limitations.

Comment: When you say "Sends project to Computer B", what are you sending?

Comment: The Whole project directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the requirements to develop with Unreal is to have Visual Studio installed. Because you are specifically working with a C++ project any attempt to open the project will also try to open Visual Studio. Since it isn't installed it errors out.

As for "why unreal imposes this limitation" is "because". It's a requirement of the engine and editor to work.

Communicating this requirement to your IT guy effectively might help them understand they need to hurry up and get it on all machines:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/GettingStarted/RecommendedSpecifications/index.html

> ## Minimum Software Requirements
>
> Minimum requirements for running the engine or editor are listed below.
>
> ### Running the Engine
>
> Operating System: Windows 7
>
> DirectX Runtime: DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)
>
> ---
>
> The requirements for programmers developing with the engine are listed below.
>
> **Developing with the Engine**
>
> All 'Running the Engine' requirements (automatically installed)
>
> Visual Studio Version
>
> - Visual Studio 2017 v15.6 or later (recommended)
> - Visual Studio 2019

Note:

> Visual Studio 2015 is no longer supported in the current release of UE4. If you are developing with the current release of UE4, you need to use either VS 2017 or VS 2019.